# How to capture PathFileExists in minifilter driver?

Tags: minifilter

I am writing a windows minifilter driver for Win7 and later.

My goal is to **capture** the **PathFileExists** API,both in minifilter pre-callback and post-callback.

The **PathFileExists** API will call **QueryOpen** in kernel space(I found this by procmon.exe),but my minifilter driver can NOT aware the **QueryOpen**'s 
 operation ,so sad :K .

After much more googling work, I improve my driver code, adding the following code to the **FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION** structure.

```
{
    IRP_MJ_QUERY_OPEN,
    0,
    mnflt_PreOperation,
    mnflt_PostOperation
},
```

But.....**It's still NOT work.** The callback function **mnflt_PreOperation** and **mnflt_PostOperation** had not been called when the **PathFileExists** API  running.

Do I miss something or completely NOT in the right way?

Thanks for any help that can be given!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need use [`IRP_MJ_NETWORK_QUERY_OPEN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/flt-parameters-for-irp-mj-network-query-open) instead `IRP_MJ_QUERY_OPEN`. so you need

```
{
    IRP_MJ_NETWORK_QUERY_OPEN,
    0,
    mnflt_PreOperation,
    mnflt_PostOperation
},
```

> `IRP_MJ_NETWORK_QUERY_OPEN` is a fast I/O operation. It is the
>   equivalent of the **`FastIoQueryOpen`** (not `FastIoQueryNetworkOpenInfo`)
>   operation.

read also [Handling IRP_MJ_NETWORK_QUERY_OPEN in a Minifilter](http://fsfilters.blogspot.com/2011/06/handling-irpmjnetworkqueryopen-in.html)

Comment: This is work! Thank you, from the bottom of my heart!

Comment: @superos, yes, if your minifilter called before luafv.sys ("uac file virtualization") - have altitude > "135000", because *the LUAFV minifilter that ships with Windows always returns STATUS_FLT_DISALLOW_FAST_IO for it, effectively failing the request and forcing it down the regular IRP_MJ_CREATE path.* it do this for have ability return `STATUS_REPARSE` for some files ( [look](http://kitrap08.blogspot.com/2010/10/blog-post_26.html) )

Comment: @superos this is not guaranteed.
I can create my own MyPathFileExits and just call CreateFile GetFileInformationByHandle CloseHandle and you'll a totally different thing in your driver.
Also depending on the filters on the stack they could dissalow fastio.
Also depening on the file being opened and it's state ( maybe it already opened with various flags/options ) the filesystem might deny fastio.
This is definitely not guaranteed and in my opinion a very bad design.